# How can I align a text object to curve without deformation?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, text-object

Is there a way to make text follow the contours of a curve without distorting the individual characters? When I use curve deform modifiers, then I get very oddly stretched text, often making it unreadable.

I have already checked these questions, they don't help:

- [Array Modifier deforming mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/array-modifier-deforming-mesh)
- [Why is the curve modifier deforming strangely?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8235/why-is-the-curve-modifier-deforming-strangely)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *text on curve* settings in the text panel.

[image]

The behavior of this setting requires practice.  Note the curve is in the XY plane, but the text is positioned in the ZX Plane.

Comment: Wow! How could one miss that? It is so obvious now :P Thanks!