# I am looking for a tutorial that shows the basic steps of the curve modifier. VERY BASIC, PLEASE

Tags: modeling

The Blender Manual which uses the monkey on a Bezier curve does not seem relevant. For my modeling, the objects would be a stick that bends as if it were a segment of an arch over a door or window. perhaps only 45deg, but as much as 180 deg. arch. and other tutorials that make things move like a snake in 3 directions are confusing for my level of experience. I just want to bend a stick on a very well defines regular arch of a specific radius.

Comment: try some of this answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/how-would-i-create-an-arch

Comment: also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32383/how-can-i-align-a-text-object-to-curve-without-deformation